# Making ctags work with CSS

Tags: css, vim, editor, ctags, exuberant-ctags

I recently started using the Exuberant Ctags program (together with vim) to generate tags files. Only problem - ctags doesn't support CSS.

Is there any way to make ctags support CSS?

Googling around I mostly found solutions telling me to recompile ctags from scratch with added css support, but I'm on Windows, so compiling ctags isn't very fun. Considering it's a pretty widely-used program, I'm hoping a better solution exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctags is extensible with regular expressions in ~/.ctags used to parse language constructs. Please see  [Add Support for a New Language](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/EXTENDING.html).

With a few additional lines in ~/.vimrc it works fine with the  [taglist plugin](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=273).